# update List of maps in Dynamodb

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Below is my DynamoDB structure:

```
{
  id : "Sample_id",
  details: {
     wf: [{
      wid: "12345",
      wname: "name_1"  
    }]
  }
}
```

Now I want add a new map object to "wf", I have tried both ADD and SET with update but both replacing the existing object with the new one.

Below is the code i tried

```
var params = {
      TableName: p_table,
      Key: {
           "id" : "Sample_id"
      },
      UpdateExpression: "SET details.wf = list_append(details.wf, :vals)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
          ":vals" : [{'wid': "98765", 'wname': 'name_2'}]
      }
};

ddb.update(params, function(err, data) { 
  if(err)   
   console.log(err);
  else
   console.log(data)
});
```

Current output with the above code:

```
{
   id : "Sample_id",
   details: {
      wf: [{
          wid: "98765",
          wname: "name_2"  
        }]
     }
 }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
   id : "Sample_id",
   details: {
      wf: [{
          wid: "12345",
          wname: "name_1"  
        },
        {
          wid: "98765",
          wname: "name_2"  
        }]
     }
 }
```

How can I achieve the expected out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my param object to below and it worked for me

Added an index 99999 (some big random index beyond which I do not expect my list to grow), in-spite of index 99999 while appending the data in lambda to the existing list it sits with next available index

```
var params = {
      TableName: p_table,
      Key: {
           "id" : "Sample_id"
      },
      UpdateExpression: "SET details.wf[999999] = :vals",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
          ":vals" : {'wid': "98765", 'wname': 'name_2'}
      }
};

ddb.update(params, function(err, data) { 
  if(err)   
   console.log(err);
  else
   console.log(data)
});
```